# Hash table of form - <key, hash table>  in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

I just want to know if it is possible to create a hashtable in java of the form `<key, hash table>`.

Essentially the first key leads me to a new hash table; then I search that table using another key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> themap = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, V>>();
```

where `K1` is the key of the "hash table", and `K2` and `V` are the key and value type of the inner "hash table".

**edit**: as @AndreiBodnarescu rightly points out, you must also choose your `Map` implementation carefully (`Map` is an interface). Ask yourself the following questions:

- is multithreading access required on the outer/inner map? If yes, consider `Hashtable` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)`;
- does insertion order matter? If yes, consider `LinkedHashMap`;
- do you want keys to be sorted? If yes, consider `TreeMap`.

Choose your implementation carefully!

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
Hashtable<KeyType,Hashtable<InnerKeyType,InnerValueType>> ht = new Hashtable<>();
```

where obviouslly the InnerValueType can still be a Hashtable

If your data structure is not accessed by multiple threads, you can repalce Hashtable with HashMap which has all the behaviour of a hashtable structure but without the synchronisation.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse that's possible. You should use `HashMap`, not `Hashtable` (because `Hashtable` is a legacy collection class that has been replaced by `HashMap` since Java 1.2).

Example:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();

mapOfMaps.put("one", new HashMap<String, Object>());
mapOfMaps.put("two", new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable> hashTable = new Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable>():
```